# Can I change the release private key in Android?

Tags: android, private-key

I have released an app on Google play store. Now I want to change the private key and release a new update for that app and  I have previous used private key, I want to replace it. Is that possible? please help me. Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Private key not keystore.

Comment: If you want to change the app key you need to remove it from the store and then reupload it as a new one, you cant modify existing app with a new key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change key used to sign released app. The only way is to unpublish current app and release new one (with different key and different packageId -> so no updates to old app users):

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your
>   app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

[Look](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#overview) official documentation, Signing in Release Mode:

> Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and
>   ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to
>   Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you
>   will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must
>   always sign all versions of your app with the same key.